# how to use and set expire for set permission sharing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my script to set "viewer" permission to gmail, and i improved it to set "viewer" permission to gmail with "expirationTime". But i met 2 big problem:

1/ Script can run, but i dont know to test if it work with "expirationTime", because if we manual set expiration, defaultime ggsheet give to you is the next day at 23:59, so i think function "expirationTime" only work with that form that mean you have to wait to the next day to test, edit v..v.. the code if it works, it is too long. 
so I dont know if the code work with "expirationTime"? (it only run already, and i setup it to the next date to make a result of test)

2/ If mine code doenst make a result, can you make me understand how to add "expirationTime" to my script, (because its concept met my works demand) and the way to test it fast.

3/ I test it many time with change minute of currentime, but it seem "expirationTime" doesnt work, but why? it sucessfully to set viewer but, "viewer" permission cant be expired after the time.

So hard, thank you for any comment to help.

```
function SetViewer(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1UfT0WriidphNwVhIMnnkOjMmkkg6jl2zIJ8xtqqR1Sg').getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataLength = getDataLength();  
  var data = getSheetValues()  
    for(var i = 1; i < dataLength; i++) {
      if(data[i]["Viewers"] !== "OK")
    continue;
    var address = app.getRange(i+1,9).getValue();
    Logger.log(address);
      var openss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(address);
    var fileId = openss.getId();
    var mail = app.getRange(i+1,2).getValue();
     var pid = Drive.Permissions.insert(
   {'role': 'reader', // writter, reader https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions
     'type': 'user',
    'value': mail,},
   //'expirationTime': '2019-07-28T00:01:00+07:00'},
   fileId,{'sendNotificationEmails': 'false' }   
    );
      Drive.Permissions.update(
      {'role': 'reader', // writter, reader https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions
       'type': 'user',
       'value': mail,
       'expirationTime': '2019-07-27T17:33:00+07:00'
      },
        fileId,''+pid.id
      );
     // DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addViewer(mail);
    }}
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('YOU_SPREADSHEET_URL_HERE');
//var fileId = ss.getId();
//DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).addEditor('EDITOR_EMAIL_ADDRESS_HERE');

function getSheetValues() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dataObject = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues(); // get every row value from the chosen sheet and put into an object
  var aObject = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < dataObject.length; i++) {
    aObject[i] = dataObject[i];
    for(var j = 0; j < aObject[i].length; j++) {
      aObject[i][dataObject[0][j]] = dataObject[i][j];
    }
  }
  return aObject;
}
function getDataLength() { //get total number of data
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  return sourceData.length;
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('QUẢN LÝ PHÂN QUYỀN')
   .addItem('Set Viewer', 'SetViewer')
   .addItem('Set Editor', 'SetEditor')
   .addItem('Remove Viewer', 'RemoveViewers')
   .addItem('Remove Editor', 'RemoveEditor')
   .addToUi();
 }
```

My expected is seting an "expirationTime" to this script to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you use Google Drive Advanced Service. But there is Google Drive API v2.

`expirationTime` is presented in v3. v3 isn't available yet for Google Drive Advanced Service.

You can use  [OAuth2 for Apps Script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) and `UrlFetchApp` for calling v3 API.

Also you can try [Apps-Script-Drive-v3-Library](https://github.com/Spencer-Easton/Apps-Script-Drive-v3-Library)

Comment: thank you, i tried to download Apps-script-Drive-v3-Library and i open that gs.file it contain a published library, then i add it to my script library, https://i.imgur.com/BqWr7jK.png , so can i ask you have i to turn off drive api v2 in advanced google service to use this library ? 
second is the publised library only have drive 1,2 ,4 and 5, it doesnt have 3, is it matter if i use 4 or 5 ? much apreciated for your reply